# Load data to teradata from sas

Tags: sas, teradata

I am trying to load data to teradata from sas. The data should be ordered by a specific field.
There is an error because of the order by clause.
Does anyone know how I can do that?

Trying to upload ordered data to teradata

Comment: If you mean you are trying to insert data into a table, there is no sorting/ordering.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Create a view with an ORDER BY clause to retrieve a result set that has a specific row order.  You might find that an unordered query retrieves rows in an expected manner, there is no contract that says it must be so.

Comment: No. If you want the results in a particular order, the ORDER BY needs to be in the SELECT statement (not a view or subquery, even for the limited cases where it may be allowed there). And of course there must be some field or set of fields in the data you can use to define the output ordering.